# Missing characters when printing from IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing

I am having some issues when printing from IE. Characters are being replaced with white-space, so it looks like they are missing when printing from IE, other browsers are printing just fine.

I have tried multiple stuff.. But no luck so far.

Below are the css code that I am using for printing:

```
@media print {      
    .content_main {

        #col-left {
            @include span(6 of $total-columns);
        } 
        #col-right  {
            @include span(6 of $total-columns last);
        }
    }

    &#left {
        @include span($total-columns);
    } 
    &#right  {
        @include span($total-columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: what 'characters' are they, exactly?

Comment: Different characters, such as k, v, g etc..

Comment: I found out that the problem lies within the html tags around the text. The issue here is that i cannot remove the html tags, how else would I differ from an <h1> to a <h2> etc.

Comment: @user2590743  this sounds similar to an issue I had with IE printing. See if the answer below works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar problem printing from IE, where older versions of IE work, while newer versions of IE drop characters, seemingly randomly, and replace their position with blanks/whitespace.

POSSIBILITY 1: MICROSOFT ISSUE IN Xpsgdiconverter.dll

If yours is the same issue, Microsoft has a hotfix for Windows that fixes this.

The Win 7 hotfix link is here:
Win 7:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2853777

There is a Win8 rollup that is reported to include a fix for this issue.  While the issue isn't mentioned for it, the correct version of the affected dll's are included.  That link is here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2855336

Here is a blog post from Marc Durdin describing the fix.
http://marc.durdin.net/2013/08/i-am-happy-to-announce-that-the-missing-characters-have-been-found/

Here is another blog post from him with the background details.
https://marc.durdin.net/2012/08/when-characters-go-astray-diagnosing-missing-characters-when-printing-with-ie9/

POSSIBILITY 2: CORRUPT FONTS NEED TO BE REMOVED/REINSTALLED
Others with similar-sounding problems have also reported an issue involving corrupted True Type fonts.  In those cases, removing the fonts with issues and then reinstalling them from the latest Microsoft font pack was indicated as resolving the issue.  To reinstall TrueType fonts that are having problems:
Identify which font it is that is having the problem.

Start/Settings/Control Panel/Fonts.
Remove the fonts that are not working correctly.  Reboot.

Start/Settings/Control Panel/Fonts
File/Install New Fonts
After installing fonts, reboot.

Start/Settings/Control Panel/Fonts
Double-click the replaced font and make sure it looks right.

I consider the first possibility as the more likely resolution, based on the description in the question.